# Sync a channel with google docs spreadsheet

Tags: import, export, sync

Is there a way to sync a google docs spreadsheet to a certain channel in ExpressionEngine. I know this might be way advanced, and the main problem i see is maintaining unique entry_id when a google row is updated or moved.

Has anyone worked on this, and can possibly share some tips, information or even code?

Answer (score 1):

These links might help you:

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/service_document

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

With DataGrab, you can point to a URL to import from. I've successfully imported directly  by using the following URL pattern

https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=1_sgsUhvWxAQrJOYluVn3jxCEcBTZqhlVBiDAPlVLEb0&exportFormat=csv

With Datagrab you can use any column as a 'primary key' for updates. Ensure on your spreadsheet side you have a unique key in one of the columns and ensure you import this as well (e.g. ImportID).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest exporting the data from Google as an CSV file and importing with the [**Datagrab addons**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/datagrab).

> **Summary of features**
>
> ```
> Import data from RSS/ATOM feeds, CSV files and XML files. Other datatypes can be added.
> Map data values to a channel’s custom fields
> Assign categories to each entry
> Assign entries to an author
> Imports can be saved and re-run — ideal for a tumblelogr
> Entries can be updated if the source data changes — keep data synchronised
> ```